# IOS Json multiple pairs value

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ipad, ios6

I have a json file thousand pairs into it  and I need the data from this `json` file.For values for the one time i get it means for first pairA1,B1,C1,D1(key values) now second time i need to skip the first values and get the second values A2,B2,C2,D2 and so on..What I am doing is

```
{list :{"A1":"1","B1":"2","C1":"3","D1":"4"},
     {"A2":"1","B2":"2","C2":"3","D2":"4"},......
 }
```

`for (NSDictionary *dic in list)
    {`

```
index=[list indexOfObject:dic];
NSString* str=[dic objectForKey:@"state"] atIndex:index]
if(string 1 isEqualtoString :str){
```

// values A1,B1,C1,D1
`return; }`

This above works fine to get first value..but I need to skip one first json pair and get the second pair on second time ..but same loop starts and gives me the first loop ..
what should I do to avoid previous values and Want the A2,B2,C2,D2

Comment: so.. are you trying to get value of "A" from the first object and value of "B" from the next object?

Comment: no I will get the A,B C,D at one time ,Next time I want second loop

Comment: what do you mean second loop?

Comment: check I have updated A2,B2,C2,D2 values

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string 1 isEqualto String:str)
```

you need to compare the string that you want here and return. (I am guessing you are verifying with the "state" key.

Comment: no I am comparing the String as str gives me the string value

Answer (score 0):

Try like this In for loop First dict values is came in A1,B1,C1,D1, and 2nd Dict values came  A2,B2,C2,D2 like that next use this value depending your functionality wise

NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!jsonArray){

NSLog (@"Erro parsing JSON :%@",e);

}else{

for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {`

NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);

}

}

Comment: No This wont work..I need to use compare method to get the needed values

Comment: what you have compare

Comment: why compare for each dictionary each loop give one dictionary